# exact match on covariates or include in a model?

Tags: logistic, predictor, case-control-study

The scenario is I have a binary outcome, a treatment group variable (3 groups) and 3 covariates. It is possible to exact match all 3 covariates on 1:N from group 1:2 and group 1:3. Would you perform the matching and run conditional LR (or Mcnemar's test?), or would you use all of the data and include the covariates in standard logistic regression? what are the pros and cons of each?